# jQuery unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token`

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$(".cartsummary .showcartsumm").click(function() {
  $(".cartsummary .cartitems").show();    
});
$(".cartsummary").hoverIntent(
function () {
 $(".cartsummary .cartitems").fadeIn();
}, 
function () {
   $(".cartsummary .cartitems").fadeOut();
}) 
nutrishowcart(0);
});

function nutrishowcart(slidedown)
{
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/CUSTminicart.aspx" + "/" + "Render",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(msg) { 
                // msg2 = eval(msg);
                // Get rid of the copyright text that kills JSON
                index = msg.indexOf('<div align="center">');
                msg2 = msg.slice(0,index);
                //msg2 = msg;
                json = eval("(" + msg2 + ")");
                $("#cartwrapper").html(json.d);

                if (slidedown==1) {
                    $(".cartsummary .cartitems").fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                }
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert("Minicart issue");
            }       

         });

}
```

This is on the last line in jquery.min.js

The error seems to be with `json = eval("(" + msg2 + ")");`

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you want to make sure that the people who can help you will find your question, you'll want to use "JavaScript" instead of "Java" in your title, and also use the javascript tag. Java and JavaScript are two very different languages.

Comment: does the below answer helped you?

Comment: no one complaining about `eval` yet? use `JSON.parse` if possible...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid JSON. It should be `json = eval("{" + msg2 + "}");` for a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

The error you spotted out is right.

To make JSON object you should use "{" instead of "("

```
json = eval("{" + msg2 + "}");
```